# OpenSSH offering wrong public key

Tags: ssh, git, openssh

I like to work with some personal Github repos from my work computer (Windows 7) occasionally so after spending way more time than I bargained for learning about how SSH works I created a different set of keys registered to my personal account and make a custom host in my `.ssh/config` file to use them with github. It looks like this:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github-personal
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/{personal-username}_github_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes

Host *
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

A while ago I managed to set up a personal repo on my work computer with the remotes looking like

```
git@github-personal:{personal-username}/{repo}
```

which worked fine. Recently though I tried to set up another and it seems like it keeps trying to offer my `~/ssh/github_rsa` identity file instead. Running `ssh -v git@github-personal` I get:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for github-personal
debug1: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/config line 13: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/config line 13: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 5: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/{personal-username}_github_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/{personal-username}_github_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/github_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/github_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/github_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/github_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/github_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.252.129]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
Hi {work-username}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 3568, received 1800 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 20744.2, received 10465.1
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Looking at these two lines:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/github_rsa
...
Hi {work-username}! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

it's clearly offering my standard work key. It looks to me the problem is somewhere around here:

```
debug1: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/config line 7: Applying options for github-personal
...
debug1: Hostname has changed; re-reading configuration
...
debug1: /c/Users/Admin/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for github.com
```

Where it initially reads the correct host configuration, but then changes its mind and reads the default github host instead. I remember having a similar problem last time and adding `IdentitiesOnly yes` was the answer but I already have that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openssh browses through the config and and is not forced to accept only one match block. The problem with your setup is that your alias `github-personal` also resolves to hostname `github.com` (the `HostName` line below) and after ssh gets to know this, it parses the config once more with this new knowledge about hostname. Also `IdentityFile` option is not exclusive and openssh can store more keys.

If you want to have it running this way, you will probably have to change the work-account to something different than then just `github.com`, for example `github-work`. This should prevent openssh to fallback to your other key. Downside is of course that you will have to reconfigure your repositories, but it should not hurt much.

Comment: Thanks Jakuje. So it seems like the host configuration is recursive, in that if I have `HostName github.com` under `Host github-personal` it will re-parse the file and then match `Host github.com`? I guess I can see why that's useful but is there no way to override it? This would work but I'd have to change all my remotes elsewhere as well, which is a bit annoying.

Comment: Yes. As your last code block shows, it is recursive. I can think of ugly workaround, putting `github-personal.com` (for example) into your `hosts` file (`%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) to point to original github IP without letting the `openssh` know.

Comment: The `hosts` file workaround actually might have been more attractive, but I realized I'm using https by default on all my other repos so using the `github-work` host for ssh seems to work just fine. I also had to remove the  github.com host entry in `~/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit.../etc/ssh/ssh_config`. Thanks, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier solution here: https://serverfault.com/a/450807/147786

Basically just add:

```
Host *
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

to the end of you `.ssh/config`